# What is an fx:controller and why do all the tutorials give me errors?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Okay so I'm following a bunch of tutorials online for Java FX and FXML, but I'm not understanding what is an fx:controller and why does my code always say there's an error with it?

Can someone tell me why does Netbeans make three classes when I make a new JavaFX project? I don't want to use FX Builder or whatever it's called, I like coding it by hand.

Why does netbeans make 3 different classes when I create a new JavaFX project? Please help I'm trying to learn this but I'm having this problem with all the tutorials I try to follow.

Here's the code that I'm having problems with:

It's giving me an error saying:
    Class does not exist: fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController
    Class does not exist: Insets

The three classes that my are in my project are:
    NotePadFX.java
    FXMLTableViewController.java
    fxml_tableview.fxml

```
<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="1.0" vgap="10" 
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>

</GridPane>
```

This is the tutorial I'm trying to follow:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second error:

> Class does not exist: Insets

make sure you have the correct import near the top of the FXML file:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
```

The first error:

> Class does not exist: fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController

might be a bit trickier. Make sure you have defined a class called `FXMLTableViewController`, and make sure the first statement is

```
package fxmltableview ;
```

Comment: This isn't an issue in the Java Code though, only in the FXML code :/

Comment: If the class doesn't exist (ie it's not in the correct package and on the classpath), then parsing the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML will throw an exception.